# Web audio analyser node - run at regular interval

Tags: timer, signal-processing, fft, web-audio-api

I want to detect an audio signal (morse code) on specific frequencies using [web audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). I retrieve the frequency data using an analyser node's `getFloatFrequencyData` function.

Now the problem: Using `setInterval()` to regularly sample the frequency data is not regular enough: the callback gets executed a few milliseconds earlier or later than expected.

**How can I retrieve the analyser's frequency data regularly exactly every few miliseconds?** I would prefer using the built-in analyser node's FFT functionality instead of resorting to manually processing the audio data via e.g. [Goertzel](https://github.com/notthetup/goertzel-node) algorithm.

Code sample with the problematic `setInterval()`:

```js
// Analyse microphone audio frequencies: 
function onStream(stream) {
  let audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(),
    source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream),
    analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser(),
    fft = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

  source.connect(analyser);

  // Doesn't execute exactly every 100ms as needed - what to do?
  setInterval(() => {
    analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(fft);
    console.log(performance.now(), fft[0]);
  }, 100);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(onStream);
```

Comment: You really don't want to use an FFT to detect morse code - inefficient and not enough time resolution. No doubt @hotpaw2 will be along shortly to give chapter and verse...

Comment: @PaulR FFT allows sampling multiple frequencies at once and thus receiving and decoding multiple signals in parallel - which is what I am going for. Doesn't Goertzel have the same time resolution as the full fledged FFT just for one frequency? I am new at audio processing, so I might be wrong.

Comment: 20 wpm morse code has a dot rate of around 15 - 20 dots / sec, so you need a time resolution somewhat better than 50 ms to resolve the dots. That means you need to run your (overlapped) FFT > 20 times / second (ideally 2x this, and even more if you want to decode faster morse). It's doable but it's very inefficient, and your audio API may not support the overlapping.

Comment: @PaulR I actually tested it with a time resolution of 20 ms which gives us about 3 samples per 20 wpm unit. Will now try the Goertzel algorithm with a ScriptProcessor node as suggested by cwilso below and see if the time resolution increases substantially for improved matching. Thank's a lot for your input, PaulR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can't really use an analyzer.  There's too much uncertainty in when it will get run, and you can't guarantee precisely when it will run.  You're better off using a ScriptProcessor for now (AudioWorklet eventually), and doing the FFT (or other recognition code) yourself.

Comment: Thought so. Will try out the ScriptProcessor for now, thanks a lot!